# mismatchexcpetion when reading file

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to read a file, and put that information into an array as an object "Train" however I keep getting an `InputMismatchException`

The file is structured like this:

```
650
10
Train
23 40
12 09
Train2
02 24
12 15
```

(and so on).

How do I properly read the file to put the info in the array?

```
public void fillArray(String info){

    try{
        File f = new File(info);
        Scanner console = new Scanner(f);
        distance = console.nextInt();
        int totalTrains = console.nextInt();
        //console.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0;i<totalTrains;i++){
            String trainName = console.nextLine();
            Time arrival =  new Time(console.nextInt(),console.nextInt());
            Time departure = new Time(console.nextInt(),console.nextInt());
            trains[i]= new Train(trainName, departure, arrival, distance);
            console.nextLine();
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Cannot locate File");
    }


}
```

[Here is the exact error message I receive when I try to access the distance that I tried to retrieve from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVVgJ.png)

Comment: What is the complete error message? Which line causes the error?

Comment: java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Schedule.fillArray(Schedule.java:45)
 at Schedule.<init>(Schedule.java:19)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message. Also be sure to show which line of your code causes the error.

Comment: Also, does your input file have a backslash and a letter en? Or do you have actual newline characters?

Comment: The file had new line characters so it is structured one line at a time. I added a screenshot of the exact error message

Comment: I have edited your question to format the input a little better. Check out the linked question and all of its answers. If you still need help after reading that, you should edit your question by copy-pasting the error message directly instead of posting a screenshot. Also indicate what line causes the error.